# mpiexec and python mpi4py gives rank 0 and size 1 for all processes

Tags: python, macos, mpi, openmpi, mpi4py

I'm on macOS 10.14. Attempting the following in `test.py`:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
i = comm.Get_rank()
p = comm.Get_size()

print('proc {}/{}'.format(i, p))
```

results in

```
proc 0/1
proc 0/1
proc 0/1
proc 0/1
```

The typical cause of this problem, as far as I can tell, is having two different MPI implementations installed. This can happen if the library used in building `mpi4py` is different than the one providing the `mpiexec` that I use to run the program.

I thought I did this carefully, though. I built `mpi4py` from source as per the instructions [provided in the docs](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html), via

```
$ python setup.py build --mpi=openmpi
```

where `openmpi` is defined in `mpi.cfg` as

```
[openmpi]
mpi_dir              = /usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/4.0.2
mpicc                = %(mpi_dir)s/bin/mpicc
mpicxx               = %(mpi_dir)s/bin/mpicxx
include_dirs         = %(mpi_dir)s/include
#libraries            = mpi
library_dirs         = %(mpi_dir)s/lib
runtime_library_dirs = %(library_dirs)s
```

I verify that the install went as intended in python:

```
$ python
>>> import mpi4py
>>> mpi4py.get_config()
{'mpicc': '/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/4.0.2/bin/mpicc', 'mpicxx': '/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/4.0.2/bin/mpicxx', 'library_dirs': '/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/4.0.2/lib', 'runtime_library_dirs': '/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/4.0.2/lib'}
```

which matches the `mpiexec` in use:

```
$ which mpiexec
/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/4.0.2/bin/mpiexec
```

and the situation is identical for `mpirun`. What am I missing? Is there some "piece" of the package which is for some reason silently expecting `mpich`, even though this all seems to add up?

Answer (score 1):

I was never able to resolve this particular issue, but instead tried uninstalling my original installation of `mpi4py`, and then instead installing `mpi4py` via `conda` in a *fresh* `miniconda` environment, which comes with it's own binaries e.g. `mpiexec`, `mpicc`... This is way cleaner than trying to muck around with the dependencies yourself. It now just works, though I need to point to the new `mpiexec` manually (since my original `openmpi` installation via `homebrew` needs to be kept as it remains a dependency for other things). I must do

```
/Users/me/miniconda3/bin/mpiexec -n 4 python ./test.py
```

I didn't try this in the first place because my conda installation was having issues unrelated to the present issue. If that's also your roadblock, just reinstall `miniconda` or whatever Anaconda distro you prefer.